# Nested Node with golang yaml.v3?

Tags: go, yaml

```yaml
## example.yaml

locationSection:
  firstLoc: Canada
  secondLoc: Korea
  thirdLoc: Italy

numberSection:
  person1: 12345
  person2: 98765
  person3: 56789
```

```golang
### this is not an exact go code but just an example...

locationSectionStructure

...
data, err := os.ReadFile(yamlFileFullPath)
if err != nil {
   fmt.Printf("[I/O Error] Falied to read this file from os.ReadFile: %s", cfgFileFullPath)
   panic(err)
}

if err := yaml.Unmarshal(data, exampleNode); err != nil {
   fmt.Printf("[Unmarshal Error] Failed to unmarshal into a yaml Node")
   panic(err)
}
...
if err := exampleNode.Decode(locationSectionNode); err != nil {
...
```

I'm utilizing the Node type from the golang yaml.v3 package.
My objective is to create an `exampleNode` that represents the data from an example.yaml file. Furthermore, I intend to generate additional nodes, namely `locationSectionNode` and `numberSectionNode`, based on the structure of `exampleNode`.

Is there a straightforward approach to achieve this? Or am I incorrectly utilizing the Node structure for this purpose?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have properly understood your request. BTW, if I did it well the following code should work for you too.

#### The `yaml` file

I used a file called `example.yaml` as per your request. The content is the following:

```yaml
locationSection:
  firstLoc: Canada
  secondLoc: Korea
  thirdLoc: Italy
numberSection:
  person1: 12345
  person2: 98765
  person3: 56789
```

I would have written it in a different way but maybe I didn't get your ideas well. Anyway, let's switch to the code that actually reads and parse it.

#### The `main.go` file

The content of the `main.go` file is what follows:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type LocationSection struct {
    FirstLoc  string `yaml:"firstLoc"`
    SecondLoc string `yaml:"secondLoc"`
    ThirdLoc  string `yaml:"thirdLoc"`
}

type NumberSection struct {
    Person1 int `yaml:"person1"`
    Person2 int `yaml:"person2"`
    Person3 int `yaml:"person3"`
}

type exampleNode struct {
    LocationSection `yaml:"locationSection"`
    NumberSection   `yaml:"numberSection"`
}

func main() {
    data, err := os.ReadFile("example.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var exampleNode exampleNode
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(data, &exampleNode); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("locations:", exampleNode.LocationSection)
    fmt.Println("numbers:", exampleNode.NumberSection)
}
```

The important part here is how I defined the structs to be used. I defined a general struct called `exampleNode` to wrap the two inner objects. Then, I defined the two structs called `LocationSection` and `NumberSection`.

> Please note the usage of the YAML tag annotations that have been used during the `unmarshal` phase. Without them, you cannot unmarshal and populate your `exampleNode` struct.

The other part of the code should be pretty straightforward.
Please let me know if this code solves your issues or do you need other help, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is interesting that I need to specify those annotations for the YAML marshal process.

Initially, I turned to the Go YAML Node due to the cumbersome nature of handling highly intricate nested YAML data. Although the example I presented was relatively straightforward, the process becomes vexing when dealing with YAML data nested at 3 to 4 levels and assigning annotations to it.

I discovered that the "gopkg.in/ini.v1" library offers a similar capability with its Sections and Keys, so I checked whether the Node could address my problem.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't get well your need. The package you provided should be used for reading/writing files, not to manipulate YAML files. If you add to the request your input and your desired output, I can adjust my answer to give you more accurate information. Let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Take note of the Node's [`Kind`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Kind) field. There are 5 kinds:

```golang
const (
    DocumentNode Kind = 1 << iota
    SequenceNode
    MappingNode
    ScalarNode
    AliasNode
)
```

2. The initial `yaml.Unmarshal` of the raw file data gets you a `DocumentNode` Node.
3. Indexing the 1st contained nodes of the `DocumentNode` Node will give you the **`exampleNode`**, which represents the data from the example.yaml file.
4. Each key and value represents a specific Node respectively in contained nodes of the **`exampleNode`**, and nested recursively.
5. So the `locationSection` and `numberSection` have 2 Nodes respectively, based on the structure of exampleNode.

Below is a full working example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("example.yaml")
    check(err)
    defer f.Close()
    input, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    check(err)

    var document yaml.Node
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(input, &document)
    check(err)
    // a MappingNode
    exampleNode := document.Content[0]
    // two string ScalarNodes
    var locationSectionKeyNode, numberSectionKeyNode *yaml.Node
    // two MappingNodes
    var locationSectionValNode, numberSectionValNode *yaml.Node
    for i := 0; i < len(exampleNode.Content); i += 2 {
        node := exampleNode.Content[i]
        if node.Kind == yaml.ScalarNode && node.Value == "locationSection" {
            locationSectionKeyNode = exampleNode.Content[i]
            locationSectionValNode = exampleNode.Content[i+1]
        }
        if node.Kind == yaml.ScalarNode && node.Value == "numberSection" {
            numberSectionKeyNode = exampleNode.Content[i]
            numberSectionValNode = exampleNode.Content[i+1]
        }
    }
    // Print locationSection Nodes
    locationSectionKey, err := yaml.Marshal(locationSectionKeyNode)
    check(err)
    fmt.Println(string(locationSectionKey))
    locationSectionVal, err := yaml.Marshal(locationSectionValNode)
    check(err)
    fmt.Println(string(locationSectionVal))

    // Print numberSection Nodes
    numberSectionKey, err := yaml.Marshal(numberSectionKeyNode)
    check(err)
    fmt.Println(string(numberSectionKey))
    numberSectionVal, err := yaml.Marshal(numberSectionValNode)
    check(err)
    fmt.Println(string(numberSectionVal))
}
```